# Do we use calculator in radians or degree while calculating prewarping analog frequency in Bilinear Transformation?

Tags: filters, lowpass-filter, bilinear-transform

Say $\omega_s=1.96\;,\omega_p=0.785$
For bilinear transformation-:

$\Omega_p=2/T*tan(\omega_p/2)$

$\Omega_s=2/T*tan(\omega_s/2)$

Should I put my calculator in radian mode or degree mode. I believe it should be in radian mode but there is written ambiguously in my textbook(somewhere degree, somewhere radians).

Comment: Since the stop and pass freq given are measured in radian put it on radian

Comment: Radians. Always radians